# How to create a loader in pdf-viewer

Tags: php, html, mysql, loader

I have a `div` that contains a `pdf-viewer`and PDF's are being loaded into it from some intrinsic calls. The documents gets loaded with a delay and the user does not gets an idea whether its loading or not. I want to put a loader into that PDF container so that the loader appears till the pages are loaded into the container(pdf-viewer). I looked around but could not make anything out of the suggestings. Here is my code where the PDF container is being created,

```
<div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer"  data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "file_ppt", $chapterId) ; ?>"> </div>
```

pdf-viewer class,

```
.pdf-viewer {


  background: #909090;
  -background: #000000;

  border: 1px solid #ddd;

  height: 400px;


  position: relative;

  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

     -moz-border-radius: 4px;

          border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}
```

Any suggestion will be highly helpful.

Comment: can you please explain how you are displaying the pdf ? did you used any module for this?

Comment: This is by using data-url attribute. JS

Comment: Please share your js code

Comment: Actually `data-url` as you can see is making the pdf's to display. its a js variable created.

Comment: display the loader image after the viewer div ,it should be hidden initially....after clicking the viewer div...make loader image to display block...and hide after the success  of pdf viewer displayed

Comment: Can something be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Most Simplest solution is use background loading gif image:

```
.pdf-container{
    position: relative;
}
.pdf-loader{
    height: 20px;   /*gif image height*/
    width: 20px;    /*gif image height*/
    position: absolute;
    background:url(../img/loading-gif.gif) left top no-repeat;
    /*These positions will show gif image at top left corner, you can adjust them later according to your requiremnets*/
    left: 0;    
    top: 0;
}
.pdf-viewer{
    z-index: 1; /*Add only z-index property in your current class, do not replace it*/
}
```

And use this div structure:

```
<div class="pdf-container">
<div class="pdf-loader"></div>
<div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer"  data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "file_ppt", $chapterId) ; ?>"> </div>
</div>
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for your answer but may I know how should i give path to my GIF in .pdf-loader class?

Comment: write a class in your css file, place image in your images folder and update path of gif image in .pdf-loader class e.g background:url(../img/loading-gif.gif) center center no-repeat;

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried the same way but the prob lem now is the GIF does not goes away once the content is loaded. It keeps running in the background and can be seen in between two pages when scrolled down .

Comment: Ok in that case use this: <div class="pdf-loader"><div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer"  data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "file_ppt", $chapterId) ; ?>"> </div></div>

Comment: Sorry to say but using the above lines completely removes the GIF. I mean its not visible at all.

Comment: give some height and width to .pdf-loader class also give position:relative, and if gif still not hiding then I will tell you some css properties for pdf-viewer class

Comment: for example your pdf will load in 100px X 100px then pdf-loader should have heigh:100px; width:100px;

Comment: if your code is online, can I have a look at it if you are still struggling?

Comment: giving width and height makes the whole pdf-viewer shrunk.

Comment: No its not online. Still in development mode. I can send you the pdf-viewer class being used here if you want to .

Comment: Yes please share the pdf-viewer class.

Comment: I have also update the answer, please have look at it, i think this will work

Comment: your code will always displays the loader in the page...he is asking to display the loader on click the viewer div. @ Lnti

Comment: I have added the pdf-viewer class. Please take a look.

Comment: I tried your updated code but this again does not shows the GIF

Comment: Not on click but when the page loads and the container loads with pdf's in it @Ranganathan.S

Comment: @Ranganathan.S yes it will always show gif but once inner content will load, gif will be hide automatically. This is why i just want to check the code, there will be just miner css tweaking and everything will work fine. Another way is, put gif in bg of pdf-viewer so once its content will be loaded, it will hide the gif

Comment: I tried this too. The GIF stays permanently here. Same as 1st case

Comment: @Inti I can provide you my css file. If you are ok then on mail.

Comment: it will be great if i can check it online

Comment: But as I said earlier I have it still in development stage, cant put this online now.